# How to create a dropdown filter list in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, ssrs-2008

I would like to create a drop down filter list based on `Region` column in my table.
I create a parameter by query like this:

[image]

I set up parameter to get the values from `region` column.

[image]

However, I got the error like this:

### The report parameter 'region' has a DefaultValue or a ValidValue that depends on the report parameter "region". Forward dependencies are not valid.

### The definition of the report '' is invalid.

An error occurred during local report processing.

Comment: You cannot use a query in a parameter that has self reference to the parameter.

Comment: It simply means, if you are creating a data set for @region parameter, then you cannot have the same parameter in the query

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a second dataset in your report to provide the list of regions to the drop-down list, for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [region]
FROM [table]
ORDER BY [region];
```

In the available values for the parameter, set the Dataset to this new dataset, & the Value & Label fields to the [region] column.

See this tutorial for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tutorial-add-a-parameter-to-your-report-report-builder?view=sql-server-ver15#AddDataset

Comment: Thank you for your input. Much appreciated it